# Download pre-built binaries post npm package installation

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Is it possible to distribute different binaries in npm package based on the client's OS?

I have URL for three binaries that were pre-built: Windows, Linux and macOS.

I want to distribute an npm package along with some `.js` scripts. After it gets installed, I need npm to try to download one of its binaries based on the client OS, and place it in the `bin` folder so I could access it through `npx` command.

I tried to download it in [`postinstall`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/using-npm/scripts#life-cycle-scripts) script, but I am not sure where to place the binary after it gets downloaded so as to access it through `npx`. Do we need to install the exe file every time when there is an update in package or can we skip if there is no change in version?

```
import { createWriteStream, readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { get } from 'https';
import { platform } from 'os';
import { exit } from 'process';

interface Asset {
    url: string;
    id: number;
    name: 'Windows.exe' | 'Darwin';
    label: string; // has tag or version of the build that would be downloaded
    content_type: string;
    state: 'uploaded';
    size: number;
    download_count: number;
    created_at: string;
    updated_at: string;
    browser_download_url: string;
}

const versionFromNames: Record<string, Asset> = {};
(JSON.parse(readFileSync('./.version').toString()) as Asset[]).forEach(
    (dist) => (versionFromNames[dist.name] = dist),
);

let interest;

switch (platform()) {
    case 'win32': {
        interest = 'Windows.exe';
        break;
    }
    case 'darwin': {
        interest = 'Darwin';
        break;
    }
    default: {
        console.warn(`yet to supported for: ${platform()}`);
        exit(0);
    }
}

const file = createWriteStream(`./${interest}`);

get(versionFromNames[interest].browser_download_url, function (resp) {
    resp.pipe(file);

    file.on('finish', () => {
        file.close();
    });
});
```

To give context, I am trying to deploy binaries generated through [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/), which adds as an add-on for npm package.

Comment: npm looks for binaries in `node_modules/.bin`; that gets added to the path when you run scripts.

Comment: Thanks, will it also delete the executable when the respective package is uninstalled?